# Keep Getting PropertyNotFoundException when populating a JSP table with Hashmap Data

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to populate a JSP table with the contents of a HashMap, but I keep getting PropertyNotFoundExceptions on the first attempt to reference it in the JSP (the firstName property). I have tried using the var['key'] and the var.value.key way of referencing it in EL and every time I get a PropertyNotFoundException. Here's the code I'm using:

The JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="orders" items="${ orderList }">
            <tr>
                <td class="name">
                    <a href="">${ orders.firstName }</a>
                </td>
                <td>${ orders.date }</td>
                <td>${ orders.product }</td>
                <td>${ orders.comments }</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

The Servlet that sets the attribute:

```
FormManager fm = new FormManager();
HashMap hm = fm.getOrder();
request.setAttribute("orderList", hm);
```

From the FormManager class:

```
public HashMap getOrder() {
        dbm = new DatabaseManager();
        Statement stmt = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM orders";
        HashMap<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] keys = { "firstName", "lastName", "phone", "email" , "date", "product", "comments", "id" };

        dbm.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pattycakes");
        dbm.connect();
        try {
            stmt = dbm.getConn().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                rs.beforeFirst();
                rs.next();
                itemMap.put(keys[i], rs.getString(i + 1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            dbm.disconnect(stmt, dbm.getConn());
        }
        return itemMap;
    }
```

There may be some issues with that code so far, because I am still in the process of writing this for a family member. All I'm concerned with is how to get past the exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JSP seems to assume that the `orderList` property will be a `Collection` of maps, but the other code you presented shows it being set as a single map with `String` keys and `String` values, representing a *single* order.  Since `orderList` is a `Map`, iterating over it via a JSTL `foreach` yields instances of `Map.Entry`, one for each entry in the map.  Those entries indeed do not have a `firstName` property, nor any of the other properties you try to extract.

Since the inappropriately-named `orderList` property really provides data for only one order, your iteration over it does not make sense.  I'm inclined to think that you're setting the wrong value for that property, but if it's really what you want then you might display the one order with JSP code along these lines:

```
<!-- no foreach -->
<tr>
    <td class="name">
        <a href="">${ orderList["firstName"] }</a>
    </td>
    <td>${ orderList["date"] }</td>
    <td>${ orderList["product"] }</td>
    <td>${ orderList["comments"] }</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I knew there were inconsistencies in my code, but didn't see that. It is meant to be a collection of Maps and a table of orders. Big mistake on my part.